# react handle this in onClick

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to control my react-router with the following component:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface INavigationMenuProps{
   routes: string[];
}

export class NavigationMenu extends React.Component<INavigationMenuProps> {

    constructor(props: INavigationMenuProps) {
        super(props);

    }

    handleButtonClick(path: string) : void {
        //this.props.history.replace(path);
        console.log(path);
    }

    render() {
        let self = this; 
        return (
            <div>   
            {
                this.props.routes.map(function(item,id) {
                    let buttonText = item.replace('/','');
                    return <button key={id} onClick={ (e) => {self.handleButtonClick(item);}}>{buttonText}</button>
                })
            }   
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

This does work. But looking at the render-function made me think if this is a proper solution. I have to safe `this` to a variable and pass a lambda-function to the on-click-handler of the button which calls the handleButtonClick-function of my `this`-variable.

Is this really the proper way of handling events?

I also tried this:

```
return <button key={id} onClick={this.handleButtonClick(item)}>{buttonText}</button>
```

But this doesn't work because `onClick` doesn't have the same signature as `handleButtonClick`

So I had to wrap my function-call and tried this:

```
return <button key={id} onClick={()=> {this.handleButtonClick(item);}}>{buttonText}</button>
```

But then I got the following error:

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type
>   annotation

1. Can someone explain why this works when I store this to a variable?
2. Is this really the way-to-do?

Comment: Any reason you're not using the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`?

Comment: Yes I could use the Link component. But my question still remains. If not for this component, then for another. I feel like I have trouble understanding a fundamental here (handle click-events).

Comment: Why do I get a downvotes? There is a question with the same problem on this side already, but in this question there is a functional-component used and the answer does not work for my class-component.

Comment: Your code makes me think you have a misunderstanding about how to best use `react-router` as well. Nothing wrong with that, as it's a complicated library. I will propose an alternative solution in an answer.

Comment: Actually, before I do that, let's dig deeper. What exactly are you trying to build here? Why can't you just build static `Link`s, such as `<Link to="/home">Home</Link>`?

Comment: I want to be able to not navigate to the link. If the link is clicked, I want to do some checks and depending on these checks decide if I change the route or not.

Comment: What sort of checks do you want to perform?

Comment: I'll be honest. I have no idea what will be done in this event. I just want to understand why I have to do such strange (at least for me) things to handle a simple click-event and if there is a better way of doing so. I should not have used the react-router as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to the line `let self = this;`, the more common approach seen in React codebases is to bind those functions in the component's constructor. So you'll want to add a line like the following at the end of your constructor:

```
this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
```

You should not run into that "implicit any" error in this case. This pattern is necessary to bind the functions to an *instance* of the component, which is what you're doing at runtime in render() by assigning `this` to `self`.

To answer your numbered questions:
1. My guess here is that TypeScript is able to resolve the type of your variables, but is not resolving `this` to an instance of the class `NavigationMenu`.
2. Yes. Your overall pattern here (writing a click handler in the component to handle whatever custom logic you may need) is correct. I see this commonly in React code & write React like that myself. The spot where you're deviating from what I've commonly seen is not binding the function in the constructor.

Comment: One thing to add - passing a regular function, not an arrow function to `this.props.routes.map` is the reason `this` can't be figured out by typescript.

Answer (score 2):

@michael-langan's answer is correct, but just to be "complete" and propose another solution... you could also take this approach (which @tmeans alludes to in his comment...):

```
import React from 'react';

export interface INavigationMenuProps{
  routes: string[];
}

export class NavigationMenu extends React.Component<INavigationMenuProps> {

  constructor(props: INavigationMenuProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleButtonClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>): void => {
    const path = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-route');
    console.log(path);
    this.props.history.replace(path);
  }

  render() { 
    return (
        <div>   
        {
            this.props.routes.map((item, id) => {
                let buttonText = item.replace('/','');
                return <button key={id} data-route={item} onClick={this.handleButtonClick }>{buttonText}</button>
            })
        }   
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

One of the nice things about this approach is that it avoid's creating an arrow function inside of the click handler of the Component, which can sometimes cause performance issues due to the way that React will "recreate" this function each time it renders.

Also, this avoids doing a bind in the constructor, which if you have a lot of click handlers in the same Component, can sometimes be messy to read.

But, all of that is really up to preference, and what linting rules you strictly are trying to follow. Like I said @michael-langan's answer is also perfectly correct.